# Как получить путь к папке Resource

Tags: java

Подскажите почему команда:

```
File fileName = new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("test.xml").getFile());
```

Выдает путь:

```
C:\Projects\MyParceXml\target\classes\test.xml
```

Как мне указать путь к папке
C:\Projects\MyParceXml\Resource
У меня такое чувство, что IDEA в упор не видит паку resources.
Так и получается
Попробовал создать файл:

```
Path testFile1 = Files.createFile(Paths.get("file1.xml"));
```

и он появился в паке src:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему файл создается в папке src?
Где это прописывается в IDEA?

Answer (score 1):

Вы не много путаете исходники с скомпилированные кодом. Вы думаете IDEA популярный ide потому что в упор не видит что то? Это не так. Java это не JavaScript когда можно на продакшен нести только исходники и всё будет хорошо.

Вернёмся к вопросу. Java Resources это файла которые будут включены в сборку, а предварительная сборка хранится в target, и во время разработки считайте что они там но явно не привязывайтесь к путям. Надеюсь что ответ помог. Удачи.

UPD.

По сути если вам нужны ресурсы для тестов то они создаются в тест каталоге по такой же аналогии и доступ к ним такой же как в основном проекте.

Comment: хорошо, а к чему тогда надо привязываться? Как правильно обратиться к файлу , который лежит в ресурсах, чтобы можно было тестить на этапе разработки и уже в скомпилированном коде?

Comment: Пользоваться ресурсами в тестах там он тоже возможны ровно как и конфигурация

Comment: Тест по сути отдельный проект в проекте